# Variable not showing after resigning

Tags: python

I am making a Tic Tac game, I have marked the places on the board with p1,p2,p3.., so if the user chooses p1, I want it to assign the X or O and show the board with the assigned value.
Problem is, the board shows the default, without any change. What am I doing wrong?

```
#Draws the 'board'
def tabla():
    p1 = ' '
    p2 = ' '
    p3 = ' '
    p4 = ' '
    p5 = ' '
    p6 = ' '
    p7 = ' '
    p8 = ' '
    p9 = ' '
    row1 = print([f'{p1}',f'{p2}',f'{p3}'])
    row2 = print([f'{p4}',f'{p5}',f'{p6}'])
    row3 = print([f'{p7}',f'{p8}',f'{p9}'])

    #Assigns x or 0    
def assigments_of_x_or_o():
    if assigments_of_x_or_o == 'X' or 'x':
        player1 = 'X'
        player2 = 'O'
        print('Player1 will be X, and player2 will be O!')
    elif assigments_of_x_or_o == 'O' or 'o':
        player1 = 'O'
        player2 = 'X'
        print('Player1 will be O, and player2 will be X!')


#Beginning of the program

print('Welcome to my game!\nPlease select the following!')
x_ili_o = input('Do you want to be X or O? ')
assigments_of_x_or_o()

tabla()
koj_place = input('Player1, what place?(1-9): ')
if koj_place == 1:
    p1 = 'X'
tabla()
```

Comment: Those `p1` etc are defined locally inside `tabla` function, they're not accessible from other function the way you try to.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov, how do I access them?

Comment: Variables defined within functions are local, and so forgotten once the functions exit. To hold the data, consider writing a class. Or, since you're only calling each function once, just get rid of them and do everything at the module level.

Comment: Even if `p1`, `p2`, etc., were accessible outside of the `tabla()` function, you're overwriting them with spaces anyway.

Comment: @jjramsey, how do you mean?

Comment: After you assign `'X'` to a variable named `p1`, you then run the `tabla()` function, which assigns `' '` to a variable named `p1`. Even if I ignore for now that the `p1` variable inside `tabla()` is a local variable, why, after `p1` has been set to `' '`, should I expect `p1` to have the value `'X'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you will be overwhelmed by Alexey's answer, you can make progress with your approach by simply moving `p1`, `p2`, ... variables outside the function, so that they don't get forgotten.

```
p1 = ' '
p2 = ' '
p3 = ' '
p4 = ' '
p5 = ' '
p6 = ' '
p7 = ' '
p8 = ' '
p9 = ' '

#Draws the 'board'
def tabla():
    row1 = print([f'{p1}',f'{p2}',f'{p3}'])
    row2 = print([f'{p4}',f'{p5}',f'{p6}'])
    row3 = print([f'{p7}',f'{p8}',f'{p9}'])

    #Assigns x or 0    
def assigments_of_x_or_o():
    if assigments_of_x_or_o == 'X' or 'x':
        player1 = 'X'
        player2 = 'O'
        print('Player1 will be X, and player2 will be O!')
    elif assigments_of_x_or_o == 'O' or 'o':
        player1 = 'O'
        player2 = 'X'
        print('Player1 will be O, and player2 will be X!')


#Beginning of the program
print('Welcome to my game!\nPlease select the following!')
x_ili_o = input('Do you want to be X or O? ')
assigments_of_x_or_o()

tabla()
koj_place = input('Player1, what place?(1-9): ')
if koj_place == 1:
    p1 = 'X'
tabla()
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you so much! But it still doesn't show the change after calling the table function?

Comment: Yes, there is another bug in your code :) The `input` function returns a string, not an integer, so comparison `koj_place == 1` is never evaluated as True.

Comment: Since `input()` returns a *string* in Python 3, `koj_place` won't ever be equal to the *integer* 1.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now! Guys like you make me wanna continue learning more, appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I allowed myself to rewrite your whole code just to show how this part could be programmed in a more... elegant and extendable way. You typically never want to use identical variables like `p1, p2, ...`, instead you should use arrays. And instead of writing separate code for each `p1, p2, ...`, you just write a loop.

```
def print_table(table):
    print('r\c ', end='')
    for col_index in range(len(table[0])):
        print(f'{col_index + 1} ', end='')
    print()
    for row_index, row in enumerate(table):
        print(f'{row_index + 1} │ ', end='')
        for value in row:
            print(f'{value} ',end='')
        print()

def print_players(players):
    for name, symbol in players.items():
        print(f'{name} will be {symbol}!')
     
def create_table(size):
    return [['·' for col in range(table_size)] for row in range(table_size)]
    
def create_players(user_choice, user_name, opponent_name):
    opponent_of = {'X':'O', 'O':'X'}
    players = { user_name: user_choice, opponent_name: opponent_of[user_choice]}
    return players
    
def input_turn(player_name):
    input_str = input(f'{player_name}, what place? (row column): ')
    return map(lambda coord: int(coord)-1, input_str.split())


# Beginning of the program

print('Welcome to my game!\nPlease select the following!')
x_ili_o = input('Do you want to be X or O? ')
players = create_players(x_ili_o.upper(), 'Player1', 'Player2')
print_players(players)

# you may choose a any size
table_size = 5
table = create_table(table_size)
print_table(table)

current_player = 'Player1'
row, col = input_turn(current_player)
table[row][col] = players[current_player]

print_table(table)
```

This prints

```
Welcome to my game!
Please select the following!
Do you want to be X or O? x
Player1 will be X!
Player2 will be O!
r\c 1 2 3 4 5 
1 │ · · · · · 
2 │ · · · · · 
3 │ · · · · · 
4 │ · · · · · 
5 │ · · · · · 
Player1, what place? (row column): 2 3
r\c 1 2 3 4 5 
1 │ · · · · · 
2 │ · · X · · 
3 │ · · · · · 
4 │ · · · · · 
5 │ · · · · ·
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your contribution and taken time! Though I am still a beginner and your code seems a bit complicated at least for my level currently.

Comment: Well, if you're using any course or a book, then learning about arrays, functions, loops is what you need to write a board game, like tic tac toe. The other complication in my code is `input_turn`, which you may skip learning for now, just remember that it allows you to split a string with "2 3" first into a list of two strings ["2", "3"] and the convert the strings into actual numbers [2, 3]

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you get the difference between the following:

```
def add_numbers():
    a = 2
    b = 3
    c = a + b
    print(c)

add_numbers() # a and b are defined inside the function you can not change them, 
              # hence the function will alway print 5


def add_numbers_2(): 
    c = a + b
    print(c)


add_numbers_2() # this will not work as the variables are not defined

def add_numbers_3(a, b): # the numbers are passed as a and b into the function 
    c = a + b
    print(c)

x = 6 
y = 7

add_numbers_3(a = x, b = y)
```

The problem is that each function has its own namespace, so the variables inside the function can not be changed from outside. Hope this helps and good luck with your project!